# What is the fringe in the context of search algorithms?

Tags: terminology, search, definitions

What is the *fringe* in the context of search algorithms?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In English, the *fringe* is (also) defined as *the outer, marginal, or extreme part of an area, group, or sphere of activity*.

In the context of AI search algorithms, the state (or search) space is usually represented as a graph, where nodes are states and the edges are the connections (or actions) between the corresponding states. If you're performing a tree (or graph) search, then the set of all nodes *at the end* of all visited paths is called the *fringe*, *frontier* or *border*.

In the picture below, the grey nodes (the lastly visited nodes of each path) form the fringe.

[image]

The video [Example Route Finding](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/cs271/lessons/48678875/concepts/486525390923) by Peter Norvig also gives some intuition behind this concept.