# How is iterative deepening A* better than A*?

Tags: search, comparison, a-star, ida-star

The iterative deepening A* search is an algorithm that can find the shortest path between a designated start node and any member of a set of goals.

The A* algorithm evaluates nodes by combining the cost to reach the node and the cost to get from the node to the goal. How is iterative deepening A* better than the A* algorithm?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) is a [best-first search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best-first_search), which means that it is an algorithm that uses both "past knowledge", gathered while exploring the search space, denoted by $g(n)$, and an [admissible heuristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic), denoted by $h(n)$, which estimates the distance to the goal node, for each node $n$. There are other best-first search algorithms, which differ only in the definition of their "evaluation function", denoted by $f(n)$. For example, the evaluation function of A* is $f(n) = g(n) + h(n)$, where $h$ is admissible.

A* is **optimal**, that is, it finds the optimal path between the starting and goal nodes or states. The optimality of A* is due to the use of an admissible heuristic function, which is a heuristic function which always underestimates the distance to the goal. A* is also **complete**, that is, it eventually finds this optimal path. However, the problem with A*, in many real-world situations, is that it has an **exponential space complexity**; more specifically, its space complexity is $\mathcal{O}(b^m)$, where $b$ is the (maximum) branching factor and $m$ is the maximum depth of the search tree. It also has a time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(b^m)$, but, in practice, it tends to find the solutions quite "fast" (for relatively small search spaces).

[IDA*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*) combines A* and [IDDFS (or IDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). It does it "well", so it gets the advantages of both algorithms. It can be thought of as the IDDFS which uses, instead of the depth, the evaluation function $f(n) = g(n) + h(n)$ as the "cost threshold" or "cutoff". In the IDA* algorithm, a child $c$ of a node $n$ is added to the [frontier (or fringe or border)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/5949/2444) if $f(c) < T$. This threshold $T$ is, at the beginning of the algorithm, the estimate of the distance to the goal from the starting node $s$, that is, $T = h(s)$. $T$ increases at each iteration of the algorithm (See the [pseudocode of the IDA* algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_A*#Pseudocode) for the details).

IDA* is also **complete** and **optimal**, but, as opposed to A*, it has a **polynomial space complexity**, more specifically, $\mathcal{O}(bd)$, where $b$ is the (maximum) branching factor and $d$ is the maximum depth fo the tree. IDA* still has an exponential time complexity of A*.

To conclude, IDA* has a better memory usage than A*. As in A* and unlike IDDFS, it concentrates on exploring the most promising nodes, and thus does not go to the same depth everywhere in the search tree (whereas ordinary IDDFS does). A* can be thought of as a dynamic programming algorithm. IDA* often ends up exploring the same nodes many times (as IDDFS), but, asymptotically, both A* and IDA* have the same exponential time complexity, that is, $\mathcal{O}(b^m)$.

So, which one is the best one? A* becomes impractical when the search space is huge, because of the memory constraints. So, in those cases, IDA* is definitely more appropriate. In general, IDA* is one of the very best optimal state space
search techniques around. However, A* is conceptually simpler than IDA*. As a consequence, in practice, A* may be easier to implement than IDA*, but, in real-world scenarios, this is not really a problem, as they are both relatively easy to implement (anyway).