# What is the space complexity of iterative deepening search?

Tags: search, branching-factors, homework, space-complexity, iddfs

When using iterative deepening, is the space complexity, $O(d)$, where $b$ is the branching factor and $d$ the length of the optimal path (assuming that there is indeed one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my other answers [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24503/2444) and [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24492/2444), the space complexity of these search algorithms is calculated by looking at the largest possible number of nodes that you may need to save in the *frontier* during the search.

*Iterative deepening search (IDS)* is a search algorithm that iteratively uses depth-first search (DFS), which has a space complexity of $O(bm)$, where $m$ is the maximum depth, with progressively bigger depths, and it turns out that its space complexity is $O(bd)$.

(Note that there is also the informed version of IDS, which uses the informed search algorithm A*, rather than DFS, known as [*iterative deepening A**](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/8909/2444)).