# What is the space complexity of breadth-first search?

Tags: search, breadth-first-search, branching-factors, space-complexity

When using the breadth-first search algorithm, is the space complexity $O(b^d)$, where $b$ is the branching factor and $d$ the length of the optimal path (assuming that there is indeed one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space complexity of the breadth-first search algorithm is $O(b^d$) *in the worst case*, and it corresponds to the largest possible number of nodes that may be stored in the [frontier](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/5951/2444) at once, where the frontier is the set of nodes (or states) that you are currently considering for expansion.

You can take a look at [section 3.5 (page 74)](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/%7Etfl2/artificial-intelligence-modern-approach.9780131038059.25368.pdf#page=96) of the book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/%7Etfl2/artificial-intelligence-modern-approach.9780131038059.25368.pdf#page=96) (3rd edition, by Norvig and Russell) for more info about the time and space complexity of BFS.