# If uniform cost search is used for bidirectional search, is it guaranteed the solution is optimal?

Tags: search, proofs, uniform-cost-search, bidirectional-search, optimality

If uniform cost search is used for both the forward and backward search in bidirectional search, is it guaranteed the solution is optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UCS is optimal (but not necessarily complete)

Let's first recall that the uniform-cost search (UCS) is optimal (i.e. if it finds a solution, [which is not guaranteed unless the costs on the edges are big enough](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24522/2444), that solution is optimal) and it expands nodes with the smallest value of the evaluation function $f(n) = g(n)$, where $g(n)$ is the length/cost of the path from the goal/start node to $n$.

### Is bidirectional search with UCS optimal?

The problem of bidirectional search with UCS for the forward and backward searches is that UCS does not proceed layer-by-layer ([as breadth-first search does, which ensures that when the forward and backward searches meet, the optimal path has been found, assuming they *both* expand one level at each iteration](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24503/2444)), so the forward search may explore one part of the search space while the backward search may explore a different part, and it could happen (although I don't have the proof: I need to think about it a little bit more!), that these searches do not meet. So, I will consider both cases:

- when the forward and backward searches do not "meet" (the worst case, in terms of time and space complexity)
- when they meet (the non-degenerate case)

#### Degenerate case

Let's consider the case when the forward search does **not** meet the backward search (the worst/degenarate case).

If we assume that [the costs on the edges are big enough](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24522/2444) and the start node $s$ is reachable from $g$ (or vice-versa), then bidirectional search eventually degenerates to two independent uniform-cost searches, which are optimal, which makes BS optimal too.

#### Non-generate case

Let's consider the case when the forward search **meets** the backward search.

To ensure optimality, we cannot just stop searching when we take off both the frontiers the same $n$. To see why, consider this example. We take off the first frontier node $n_1$ with cost $N$, then we take off the same frontier node $n_2$ with cost $N+10$. Meanwhile, we take off the *other* frontier node $n_2$ with cost $K$ and the node $n_1$ with cost $K + 1$. So, we have two paths: one with cost $N+(K + 1)$ and one with cost $(N+10)+K$, which is bigger than $N+(K + 1)$, but we took off both frontiers $n_2$ first.

See [the other answer](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/24552/2444) for more details and resources that could be helpful to understand the appropriate stopping condition for the BS.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the stopping condition.  If the stopping condition is "stop as soon as any vertex is encountered by both the forward and backward scan", then bidirectional uniform-cost search is not a correct algorithm -- it is not guaranteed to output the optimal path.  But it is possible to adjust the stopping condition to make bidirectional uniform-cost search guaranteed to output an optimal solution.

See the following resources for details, and the correct stopping condition:

[Computing Point-to-Point Shortest Paths from External Memory](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.911&rep=rep1&type=pdf).  Andrew V. Goldberg, Renato F. Werneck.  ALENEX/ANALCO 2005.

[Point-to-point shortest path algorithms with preprocessing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/goldberg-sofsem07.pdf).  Andrew V. Goldberg.  International Conference on Current Trends in Theory and Practice of Computer Science, 2007.

[Efficient Point-to-Point Shortest Path Algorithms](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr06/cos423/Handouts/EPP%20shortest%20path%20algorithms.pdf).  Andrew V. Goldberg, Chris Harrelson, Haim Kaplan, Renato F. Wemeck.

I found these resources by looking at the Wikipedia article on [bidirectional search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search); it mentions that the termination condition has been articulated by Andrew Goldberg et al and cites the third reference above.  Then a quick search on Google Scholar immediately turned up the other papers as well.

Lesson for the future: It can be useful to spend a little time checking standard resources (such as Wikipedia and textbooks), and checking the literature (e.g., with Google Scholar).  Many natural questions have already been answered in the literature.

Comment: It may be helpful to know that UCS is essentially the same thing as Dijkstra's algorithm.